# why are these two ways of accessing parts of C++ map pairs different

Tags: c++, for-loop, dictionary, stdmap, std-pair

I was puzzled when I received an error that suggested I use a `.` operator to access the value in a pair from a map because when I changed it in two places in code I received a new error that suggested that I use a `->` in the second place in code. I listened to the naggy compiler. Why did I need to?

Here's what I was doing:

In a range based for loop, I want the value from the key-value pair which could be exampled:

```
std::map<std::string, aclass> mapthings;
...
for (auto& it : mapthings) {
    fout << it.second.stringify();
}
```

I'm also using the same `mapthings` but using the `find()` function:

```
return (mapthings.find(name))->second;
```

Comment: OT, but `(mapthings.find(name))->second;` will cause undefined behaviour if the `name` is not found; so that piece of code probably needs to be rewritten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code snippet

```
std::map<std::string, aclass> mapthings;
...
for (auto& it : mapthings) {
    fout << it.second.stringify();
}
```

`it` is of type value_type of `std::map<std::string, aclass>` that corresponds to type

```
std::pair<const std::string, aclass>
```

So to access members of an object of this type you have to use operator .

In this code snippet

```
return (mapthings.find(name))->second;
```

method `find` returns iterator that points to the target record of the map or to iterator returned by `end()`. Iterators are like pointers. So you need to use operator -> to access members of the pointed object.

Take into account that you could write simpler

```
return mapthings.find( name )->second;
```

or

```
return ( *mapthings.find( name ) ).second;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions at the end of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because find return mapthings::iterator,which stores a pointer to mapthings::value_type.
While auto& it is a object of mapthings::value_type.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example range-based for loop gives object directly. So you can use `.`.
In the second example `find` gives you  iterator to the object. That compels you to use `->` because you need object itself.

Answer (score 1):

When you use this code, you get a reference to a std::pair containing your data

```
for (auto& it : mapthings) {
    fout << it.second.stringify();
}
```

In the second example, find returns an iterator which needs to be dereferenced to be read

Answer (score 1):

In the first one, you get a `std::map::value_type&`, which is defined to be `std::pair<const Key, T>`. This method is best for accessing all the members of the map.

In the second one, you get a `std::map::iterator`. `std::map::iterator` has `operator->` overloaded, which returns a `std::map::value_type*`. This method is best for `find`, `upper_bound`, `lower_bound`, etc. since you are performing queries on the map. The map might not hold a member corresponding to the `key` used in the query.